# How to add custom data to overlay in Google Maps for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can i add custom data to GMSGroundOverlay images in Google Maps for iOS? I am successfully passing data on markers when clicked with the built-in "marker.userData" but the ground overlays dont have that property?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i figured this out if it's helpful to anyone else. Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works.

1.) I extended the GMSGroundOverlay class in the map's main .swift file

```html
extension GMSGroundOverlay {
    private struct customData {
        static var userData:Any? = nil
    }
    var userData:Any? {
        get {
            return customData.userData
        }
        set {
            customData.userData = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

2.) I pass the data on the overlay before overlays are added to map

```html
let overlayData:[String:Any] = ["id":id,"html":html,"picture":picture,"photos":photos]
overlay.userData = overlayData
```

3.) I receive the data when overlays are clicked

```html
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapOverlay overlay: GMSGroundOverlay)  -> Bool {
        print("# You tapped overlay with data: ")
        for (key,value) in overlay.userData as! [String:Any] {
            print("#    \(key) = \(value)")
        }
        return false
    }
```